# query not resolving formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to concatenate data in QUERY formula from cell as shown in image
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EdUX.jpg)
Formula is :=QUERY(CONCATENATE(A9,"!A2:D5"),"Select A,B")
picking data_range from another cell
how can I get it?

picking "data_range" from another cell
I want to "data_range" in query changeable

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477243/1510610. Please check the answer there.

Comment: solution is not for data range

Comment: Dynamic data range I believe is not possible, at least directly in google sheet. Alternative is to create data range first ( like concatenation) and then pick from these computed cells. Does that help?
  
It might be possible using api https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(A9&"!A2:D5"); "select Col1,Col2"; )
```